# Ajax select post with real-time message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get real-time message and response from this POST, but doesn't work for me. I want to display in this Ajax text from **timezone.php** - `error` or `success` Where I made mistake?

**HTML**

```
<form id="timezone_form">
  <select name="timezone_select">
    <option value="1">test 1</option>
    <option value="2">test 2</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="settings_ajax_message"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#timezone_form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "timezone.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    })

    .done(function(data) {
      $("#settings_ajax_message").html(data);
    })

    .fail(function() {
      $("#settings_ajax_message").html(data);
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

**timezone.php**

```
<?php

  $timezone = $_POST['timezone_select'];
  if ($timezone == 1) {
    echo '<div class="ch-mes-fixed-warning-animation"><div class="ch-mes-warning">error</div></div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="ch-mes-fixed-success"><div class="ch-mes-success">success</div></div>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Your timezone.php located at same directory?

Comment: @PerfectoWeb Yes. Every file in one folder.

Comment: You need to prevent the default action of the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have to understand why your fail function would be called:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  // Prevent the form from actually submitting to the server
  e.preventDefault();

  $("#timezone_form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "timezone.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    })

    // Status code 200-299 was returned. The data was successfully returned from the server.
    // PHP by default will always return 200 (Which signifys that the server processed the data, and is returning it)
    .done(function(data) {
      $("#settings_ajax_message").html(data);
    })

    // Status 300+ was returned from the server. This usually indicates an error on the server (ie. 404 not found, or 500 server error)
    .fail(function() {
      $("#settings_ajax_message").html(data);
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

You have 2 ways to handle this. 1, have your server actually return an error (Usually the preferred route for an API):

```
header("HTTP/1.0 422 Error");
```

In most cases, you should catch bad errors with `.fail` like if your server craps out. Have your server return 200 (Which will process the done function), but check for an error property:

```
<?php
  // Tell javascript this is a json response:
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];
  if ($timezone == 1) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => '<div class="ch-mes-fixed-warning-animation"><div class="ch-mes-warning">error</div></div>']);
  } else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => false, 'message' => '<div class="ch-mes-fixed-success"><div class="ch-mes-success">success</div></div>');
  }

?>
```

And your ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#timezone_form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "timezone.php",
      dataType: 'json', //IMPORTANT! PROCESS AS JSON
      data: $(this).serialize()
    })

    .done(function(data) {
       if (data.error) {
         console.log(data);
         //Do something with the error
         $("#settings_ajax_message").html(data.message);
       } else {
         //No error. data.message will be the message
       }
    })

    .fail(function() {
      $("#settings_ajax_message").html(data);
    });

    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, your field name is **timezone_select**, look here: `<select name="timezone_select">`. In PHP you checking another name: `$timezone = $_POST['timezone'];`